# In the Eclipse Debugger (for Java), is there a way to inspect arbitrary values?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm wondering if there is a way to look at the values of non-declared variables as they get passed into a function, *after that function has been executed*. For example, if I am debugging and the line

```
foo.setBar(baz.getBar());
```

has already been passed (but is still within scope), how can I see the value of what got passed in to `setBar()`? I know that I can see this many other ways, for instance by stepping into the `setBar()` call, or by assigning `baz.getBar()` to a temporary variable - but that's not what I'm asking.

Edit: Basically, I feel penalized (by losing the ability to see certain information) while debugging, just because I'm not declaring every variable.

And, I know I could inspect `bar` after the fact (if I know it hadn't changed) but in this case it's not so simple because I'm dealing with objects that aren't just POJOs or JavaBeans (the object that brought this question up is an HTTP request - and yes, I already did try inspecting it).

Comment: to be even more specific, you would like to know what got passed into foo.setBar(...) even if it gets called twice?  ie, what was the first value passed in and what was the second?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the Debug perspective, open the display window (Window => Show View => Display), write the code that you want to display (e.g., `baz.getBar()`), select it, and then right click and choose "Display" or use the shortcut to display its value.

Comment: Almost - I had to select the text I wanted to execute first. Thank you! I never knew about that view.

Comment: I used Inspect all the time, but this is really useful when you want to try arbitrary bits of code indeed. Much less cumbersome than editing the Expressions all the time. Thanks for yet another hidden Eclipse feature! =)

Answer (score 11):

A by far easier way is to select an expression (here: baz.getBar()) and press CTRL+SHIFT+I (for inspect). This opens a tooltip like window with all you want to know.

Comment: Indeed! Though, less flexible.

Answer (score 5):

And of course you can use "Expressions" view (Window -> Show View -> Expressions).

Answer (score 0):

in your Expressions view, add the following expression

```
baz.getBar()
```

and it will be dispayed while debugging (if it is visible to the debugger ofcourse)

Comment: This is no different from [Serge's answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1313418/139010)